# Let AWS EKS node to access RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc

I would like to let my AWS EKS node to communicate with AWS RDS. Both of them are in the same subscription and region so no need to implement any sci-fi architectures. Just a simple one would be enough.

I started to investigate and I found a couple of stackoverflow threads.

1. [This is the first idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775542/aws-eks-node-to-access-rds#answer-68844330) where the *Security Groups for Pods* is "implemented". This is not my case. I'm happy to share the RDS with all the whole nodes. Am I wrong?
2. [This is the second idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775542/aws-eks-node-to-access-rds#answer-68775661) (actually in the same thread) where they suggest to put all the different resources (RDS and EKS) in the same VPC (shared?). Is it a good idea?
3. And finally [here](https://dev.to/bensooraj/accessing-amazon-rds-from-aws-eks-2pc3#4-lets-build-the-bridge) the *VPC Peering Connection* is suggested as a good solution. Is it really a good solution? I can see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/05/amazon-vpc-announces-pricing-change-for-vpc-peering/) the announcement which stands that: "*all data transfer over a VPC Peering connection that stays within an Availability Zone (AZ) is now free*". This is good, but looks like an enterprise solution for a simple problem.

Can you help me here in choosing a good solution which can properly fit my scenario? Can I set a proper IAM/Roles instead?

Comment: You mention "subscription", this is Azure's concept, for AWS you have accounts. You should use 3-tier design and create separated subnets for DB, read this `https://stratus10.com/blog/aws-best-practices-3-tier-infrastructure`. Using security groups for pods is your choice, you can use it if you want (not mandatory). If you create only 1 VPC, you don't need VPC peering (need 2 VPCs for this feature)

Comment: You should do a lab, create EKS, MySQL RDS and test it.